# mysql.infoschema@localhost does not exist

Tags: mysql, database

**the user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema@localhost') does not exist**

Please help me to solve this issue, i've tried many solutions which has a green check, it still can't solve.
The issue occurs after i accidentally changed all mysql user password, then created new user. When login with mysql workbench, the error show.

I tried

- **mysql_upgrade** *[return the user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema@localhost') does not exist]*
- **UPDATE mysql.proc** *[return proc table does not exist]*
- **GRANT ALL** *[return the user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema@localhost') does not exist]*

I can't export, import, check tables cause it always says the user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema@localhost') does not exist

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have no user as 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost'. It is used as the DEFINER for INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. It is a default user that should already be there. If it is not:

See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reserved-users.html).

Create user as

`create user 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost' identified by 'password';`

And grant it privileges

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost';
```

Comment: FYI - Tried that and `Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.user]` also, your doc link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I try many recommendations but when I probe repair th databases the command mysql_upgrade don't work, try to start mysql with the option upgrade, like this.

```
mysqld --user=mysql --upgrade=FORCE
```

works for me!